# Mongoose MongoDb not showing schemas or models in Node Shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and mongodb. After creating my schemas and models:

```
one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/data $ tree 
.
|-- models
|   |-- cpu.js
|   |-- httpPort.js
|   |-- memory.js
|   `-- network.js
`-- schemas
    |-- cpu.js
    |-- http_port.js
    |-- memory.js
    `-- network.js

2 directories, 8 files
```

one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/data $ cat models/cpu.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var CpuSchema = require(../schemas/cpu);

var Cpu = mongoose.model('Cpu', CpuSchema);

module.exports = Cpu;
```

one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/data $ cat schemas/cpu.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,

var CpuSchema = new Schema({
    'timeStamp' : { type : Date, index: true },
    "avaiable" : Boolean,
    "status" : String,
    "metrics" : [ "15m": [ "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                          ],
                   "5m": [ "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                          ],
                   "1m": [ "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                         ]
                ]
})

module.exports = CpuSchema;

one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/data $
```

**When connecting to the database in the node shell, I am not showing anything for schemas or models. Why is this?**

```
> var dbURL = 'mongodb://localhost/database';
undefined
> var db = require('mongoose').connect(dbURL);
undefined
> db


> db
{ connections: 
   [ { base: [Circular],
       collections: {},
       models: {},
       replica: false,
       hosts: null,
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 27017,
       user: undefined,
       pass: undefined,
       name: 'database',
       options: [Object],
       otherDbs: [],
       _readyState: 1,
       _closeCalled: false,
       _hasOpened: true,
       _listening: true,
       _events: {},
       db: [Object] } ],
  plugins: [],
  models: {},
  modelSchemas: {},
  options: { pluralization: true } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `require` your model in the shell. Mongoose won't recognize that you've defined a model until you've called `mongoose.model`, and that's only called when you require `models/cpu.js`.